# How to get the event target of a button and not what's inside the button when clicked

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have an svg wrapped inside of a button element. I am making a dropdown toggle. When you click `document`, it closes the button. I'm using [rxjs](https://rxjs.dev/) but any vanilla code should do the same.

**React**

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react'
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs'

// Inside a render function
const buttonEl = useRef(null)
const [showDropdown, setShowdropdown] = useState(false)

useEffect(() => {
    let isSubscribed = true

    if (isSubscribed) {
      fromEvent(document, 'click').subscribe((e) => {
        console.log(e.target === buttonEl.current) // true; somethings false

        // When same element is clicked, do not close dropdown.
        if (e.target === buttonEl.current) { return }
        setShowdropdown(false)
      });
    }

    return () => { isSubscribed = false }
  }, [])

<button
  ref={buttonEl} 
  className="Create__action" 
  onClick={() => {}}>
  <svg>...</svg>
</button>
```

I've omitted the toggle function and the dropdown `ul` element.

Since the svg is inside the button, most times the `event` is picking up the svg instead of the button's. My svg is small, say, "three vertical dots". How to ensure the event picks up the button so that my `setShowdropdown` fires?

Console logging the event shows me nothing unique. Sometimes the `target` is the `button` other times it's the `path` of the svg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [`Node.contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains).

To determine if `e.target` is a descendant of the button, use:

`buttonEl.current.contains(e.target)`.